# Activity com.test.MainActivity has leaked window android.widget.LinearLayout@41ab4238

Tags: android

What is the leaking here, I dont understand.

```
 06-07 17:04:50.319: E/WindowManager(23232): Activity com.test.MainActivity has leaked window android.widget.LinearLayout@41ab4238 that was originally added here
06-07 17:04:50.319: E/WindowManager(23232): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.test.MainActivity has leaked window android.widget.LinearLayout@41ab4238 that was originally added here
06-07 17:04:50.319: E/WindowManager(23232):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:403)
06-07 17:04:50.319: E/WindowManager(23232):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
06-07 17:04:50.319: E/WindowManager(23232):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
06-07 17:04:50.319: E/WindowManager(23232):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
06-07 17:04:50.319: E/WindowManager(23232):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
06-07 17:04:50.319: E/WindowManager(23232):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:992)
06-07 17:04:50.319: E/WindowManager(23232):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:901)
06-07 17:04:50.319: E/WindowManager(23232):     at com.test.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:91)
```

My Code is as follows

### Activity Class

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
        popupWindow = new SettingsPopupWindow(popupView, 150, 300);  
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 0, 0);
}

protected void initMenuButtonPopup()
{
    btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menuButton);
    btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

### Popup class

```
public class SettingsPopupWindow extends PopupWindow implements OnClickListener{
View vw;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    dismiss();

}

public SettingsPopupWindow(View contentView, int width, int height)
{
    super(contentView, width, height);
    this.vw = contentView;
    Button btnDismiss = (Button)vw.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

}

Comment: When did this happen ? When you closed your popup ?

Comment: looks like. I see this intermittently

Comment: Is clicking on the popup window the only way to close it? No back button/click outside/keypress that may do it?

Comment: I am to implement a popup window that opens up on a 3 vertical dot button. Do u suspect any leaking point here...

Comment: Could you try to dismiss the popup on the UI thread ? (runOnUiThread)

Comment: so should i do like this ` runOnUiThread( dismiss());`

Comment: i am not able to compile the code if I have runOnUiThread( dismiss());

Comment: I tried in OnClick runOnUiThread(
    new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
      
      dismiss();
     }
    }
    );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `dismiss` your `PopUpWindow` in the same class, which holds the reference of it. 
So move your `onClick` behavior in the `Activity`.